# Array push is overwriting the existing array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to construct an array of the data responses from each user.

```
import * as localforage from "localforage";

mobileData: any[] = [];

constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

ngOninit(){

    for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
        this.getData(users.id);
    }
}

getData(id) {

    this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe(response => {

        this.dataStorage(response);
    });
}

dataStorage(payload: any) {

    this.mobileData.push(payload);

    console.log("mobile data Array ", this.mobileData);

    if(this.mobileData.lenth === this.users.length){

       localforage.setItem("usersData", this.mobileData);
    }
}
```

Problem is my array keeps getting overwritten with the new data instead of appending.

```
//service
  getData(id:any): Observable<any> {
    let method                      = "GET";
    let url                             = "/api/getData";
    let data                            = "id="+id;
    let header:Headers                  = new Headers();
     header.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );

     return this.http.request(this.newRequest(method,url,data,header))
       .map(this.extractData)
       .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

This is my first time posting. Please let me know if more information is required to assist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `this.mobileDataStorage(response);` should be `this.dataStorage(response);`.

Comment: Moreover You're console.log(this.freeResourcesData) not console.log(this.mobileData)

Comment: @null thanks, edited

Comment: @AmitChigadani edited.

Comment: If you print the response inside `getData.subscribe(...` of component, does it print as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Simple assign `response` to `mobileData` in subscribe and use `mobileData` in your templates to display it.

```
mobileData = [];

this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe(response => {
    this.mobileData = response;
});
```

Comment: edited the question. motivation behind this approach. I want to construct an array of the responses so I can store it using the localForage.

Comment: With response you should get an array. What I am thinking right now is that you think that you get plenty of items and you are looping through those items and push them one by one to mobileData. If I am right then it is not the way it is. You get an array of items in response and simply assign it to mobileData. OR see post your response if this is not the case.

Comment: I could do this too but my response is really big to map and push the fields 1 by 1

Answer (score 0):

Change `ngOninit` to `ngOnInit`. I am not seeing any other wrong with your code. Anyway I created [this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xn1nr8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for you. Compare it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
 mobileData : any[] = [];
 isFinished = false;

 constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

 ngOnInit(){
  for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
   this.getData(users.id);
  }
 }

 getData(id) {
  this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe(response => {
   this.dataStorage(response);
  });
 }
 
 dataStorage(payload: any) {
  this.mobileData.push(payload);
  console.log("mobile data Array ", this.mobileData);
  if(this.mobileData.length === this.users.length){
     localforage.setItem("usersData", this.mobileData);
  }
 }
}
```